# What's wrong with $cos(t) /t$ and $e^{-t^2}$?

Tags: integration

Usually whenever these functions pop up in the computation of a proper integral,  one is stucked finding their antiderivative.

Has it been proved that their antiderivative has no closed form in terms of a polynomial in $sin, cos, tan, exp, ln,... $?

EDIT: the question is indeed a duplicate.

For French speakers, this issue is completely assessed here 
[1995 Competitive exam](http://www.mathsland.com/Forum/Uploads/3489a9494dbdc61a1fe1663d8001b67bm95lm1ea%5B1%5D.pdf)

Comment: This has been proven. The answers to a similar question contain good references: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral